# TypeError: ShallowWrapper::dive() can not be called on Host Components

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm following the goreact testess videos and trying here. I'm not having success in my attempts. I have the following error:

`TypeError: ShallowWrapper :: dive () can not be called on Host Components`

Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WORpE.jpg

The project is in git, if you'd like to see the example as a whole better: https://github.com/henriqueweiand/reactjs-crud-state-test

Answer (score 5):

Having a quick look at your project, you'll need to use something along the lines of...

```
wrapper
  .find('DocumentosTable')
  .dive()
  .find('FaTrash')
  .first()
  .simulate('click');
```

Notice the note in the documents which should explain why you're seeing that error.

`Dive can only be called on a wrapper of a single non-DOM component element node, otherwise it will throw an error.`

For more information on dive go [here](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html)

Comment: Ok, I made some updates on the project and I had some progress ... but now my problem is with the click simulation.

https://github.com/henriqueweiand/reactjs-crud-state-test/blob/master/src/pages/tests/formDocumentos.test.js